# Passing command line arguments to the benhmark program using stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, haskell-criterion

I'm using [stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) as a build tool, and [criterion](http://www.serpentine.com/criterion/) as benchmarking library. To run the benchmarks I execute the following command:

```
stack bench
```

Criterion accepts command line arguments to specify where the output should be written to. I would like to pass these arguments to the executable built and run by `stack`. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
stack bench --benchmark-arguments "--arguments --for --criterion"
```

(It's among options listed under `stack bench --help`.)